# Not able to add any WebPart on the site page

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, web-parts, sharepoint-online

I have created a "Team Site" on SharePoint online. When I edit a site page, I am not able to view any option of adding a web part on the page. All I can see are following options. Please click the link to see the options. I don't see any web part option there.

[image: options image]

I believe there are some features that need to be activated on this site collection. Does anybody know which features need to be activated here to enable web parts on the page?

Answer (score 0):

You can't add web part to New experience mode Sharepoint page. At least not for now. But you can create a page in Classic mode, it's the same as it was in SP2013.

[How to do it - Read this article](http://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-bypass-the-new-modern-team-site-page-experience/)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, WebPart doesn't work in New Experience. You need to be in Classic View to add the WebPart.